Where to see triggers in Visual Studio Code
I have a few triggers that I can see in the Developer's Console.  I cannot find them in Visual Studio Code.  I am looking for guidance as to where I should see them.  I am in the Org Browser feature of VSC and don't see them.

They will appear in <path>/main/default/triggers, where <path> is configured in sfdx-project.json. Try the following command in your console:
sf project retrieve start -o orgAlias -m ApexTrigger

Alternatively, in the Org Browser, they should appear in <org-name>/Apex Triggers.

You may need to refresh the metadata if this is a new trigger (use the Refresh button on the context menu).
If you still don't see this option, you may need to restart VS Code. Make sure you're on the latest versions of SF CLI, VS Code, and the Salesforce Extension Bundle.
